# How can I find out what is hanging Fedora when it is booting?

Tags: linux, boot, fedora

I'm having problems booting up my Fedora 14 system.  I see the Fedora splash screen (the one with the egg-like logo that colorizes as it loads); the logo fills up completely and then everything hangs - all I see is the egg logo, and nothing else is ever displayed.  I also can't get to any of the ttys via the CTRL-F1 sequences.

I can boot into single user mode just fine.  The install scripts all run just fine.  The system itself is actually up an running, so I suspect this is either something in the KDE startup, or after init processes all of the start up scripts.

I'm assuming this isn't a startup script problem, because I see a "started XXX" message for every service in the rc.5 directory - in other words, all the startup scripts ran from rc.5.

So, how do I find out what is hanging?  I'm not seeing anything in /var/log/messages, and pstree didn't tell me much about what init was doing.

I used to be able to follow inittab to see all the things it did at boot, but since inittab was stripped of everything it used to do a few releases ago, I don't know what init is doing anymore.

Any suggestions would be most helpful and appreciated.

Comment: Hm... Can you disable the splash screen from your boot loader?

Comment: I can, I booted to "single" mode.  I see the startup scripts starting, it makes it all the way to "starting smartd" and then nothing else comes up on the console, or in /var/log/messages.  At that point the runlevel is 5, smarted is the last startup script (S99), and init appears to be done, but something isn't finishing cleanly somewhere.  I'd be happy to post any logs you think might be useful.

Comment: What I'd *really* like to find out is what is init doing?  I used to be able to tell from inittab, but all that "code" is gone now.  Where did it go?

Answer (score 0):

You might have some luck with **bootchartd**. That is, if you can install it from single user mode. Once installed, boot with `init=<path_to_your_bootchartd_binary>` bootloader option, let it hang and run at least 2 or 3 minutes (in order to let bootchartd store an image), then reboot with any livecd and look at `/var/log/bootchart.png`. That should give you a clue...

Comment: Thanks for the info jankes, I'll try that next chance I get (I ended up switching back to Windows over this, believe it or not).